# objects.all() queryset not working with view to template; many-to-one relationship

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to make this template call a function that has worked in the past with a many-to-many relationship. This time it is a many-to-one.

the detail.html template

```
{{ icecreamflavor.name.all }}
```

The view:

```
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
    from django.views import generic

    from .models import IceCream, IceCreamFlavor

    # Create your views here.


    class IndexView(generic.ListView):
        template_name = 'ice_cream/index.html'
        context_object_name = 'ice_cream_list'

        def get_queryset(self):
            return IceCream.objects.order_by('brand')

    class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
        model = IceCreamFlavor
        template_name = 'ice_cream/detail.html'
```

2 Models:

```
class IceCream(models.Model):
    ice_cream_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.brand


class IceCreamFlavor(models.Model): 
    ice_cream_flavor_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(IceCream)    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is a many to one relationship, and I believe that in my view I have something messed up at the model for the DetailView. I want to use the objects.all() method to simply call all the flavors of the ice cream in the detail view.

Nothing comes up. The documentation in the tutorial has me confounded a bit. The IndexView works and show up all the brands; just need DetailView to bring up all the flavors; I will format later. For the record, `{{ icecreamflavor }}` in the detail.html template does bring up only one flavor and not all of them. I believe it is something about instances..

Comment: You have 2 views there, which one are you using ? IndexView ? The DetailView only send 1 object to the template, the Object you want to see details. And in the template you can't make queries to database, you have to send the objects.all() from the view,  like in the IndexView the part that says `def get_queryset()`

Comment: I am trying to use the DetailView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Index View

First of all, when you are using [Django Generic List View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) the object list in the template is called `object_list`. Check the above link to see django documentation.

So to show all the IceCream names in the **Index** template you should do:

```
{% for item in object_list %}
    {{item.brand}}
{% endfor %}
```

To access the IceCreamFlavors of an IceCream you should do like this:

```
{% for item in object_list %}
    {{item.icecreamflavor_set.all}}      
{% endfor %}
```

`{{item.icecreamflavor_set.all}}` <-- Check that I'm using *icereamflavor**_set***

When the foreign key is from IceCreamFlavor to IceCream, and you want to access from IceCream to IceCreamFlavor you need to add **_set** to the model's name.

## Detail View

The second view is a Django Generic DetailView so it's completely normal behaviour that the view only send one item to the template.

If you want to pass all the items you need to change the view from DetailView to ListView.

I recommend you to check both documentations about ListView and DetailView to understand better what's happening there.

Also I recommend you to check [Django: Backward relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)

Comment: My index view code for the item.brand is essentially the same. I need this to be done for the detail view. I want the flavors to be shown in the detailview and NOT in the indexview. I hope this is clear. Thanks.

Comment: I know how to get it to show in the index, the problem is the detailview which is when a new page is loaded.

Comment: Ok. Sounds like this "backwards relationships" is key to understanding object retrieval. Anways, I got it working in the DetailView. I changed the model to ``IceCream`` instead of ``IceCreamFlavor`` in the view for DetailView, and then in the template for detail.html I simply changed it to ``{{  icecream.icecreamflavor_set.all }}``.

Comment: The key was the difference in relationships it seams. In my other app I have code like this in the same template and detailview: ``{{ game.company.all }}`` and it works as in it displays all the companies. However, when I change it to ``{{ game.company_set.all }}``, nothing shows.

Comment: So there is a big difference between why ``{{ game.company.all }} `` works in one app with (almost identical views and template) AND ``{{ icecream.icecreamflavor_set.all }}``. One is using the ``all()`` method and the other is using ``set.all()``.